Extract PDU info from pcapng file using scapy
I have pcapng file, and I want to extract information from layers. When I open file in Wireshark, I have following layers: Ethernet, VLAN, IpV6, User Diagram protocol, PDU Transport Protocol. I have no problems with extracting every layers except PDU. How can I extract PDU info (id, length, payload) in Python using scapy?
I tried to find pdu class in scapy documentation (I'm using scapy 2.5.0), but I didn't have any success.
